# How to test whether the average return on S(USD/AUD) of the last 30 days is significantly different from zero at the 5% level of significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have daily returns on S(USD/AUD). Now how to test whether average return of last 30 days is significantly different from zero at 5% level of significance ?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for a so-called "HAC"-test, a "heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation consistent" test for $\mu=\mu_0$:
$$
t_{HAC}=\frac{\bar{Y}_T-\mu_0}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\gamma_j}{T}}}
$$
We can then approximately (i.e. for $T$ sufficiently large) argue that, under $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$
$$
t_{HAC}\stackrel{a}{\sim}N(0,1)
$$
How can we estimate $J=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\gamma_j$? In practice, for a sample size $T$, we can calculate autocovariances up to order at most $T-1$. A plausible idea then is
$$
J_T\equiv\hat{\gamma}_0+2\sum_{j=1}^{T-1}\hat{\gamma}_j
$$
Clearly the higher order terms will be estimated from very few observations. It turns out that using all possible $\hat{\gamma}_j$ as above leads to an inconsistent estimator.

Consistent estimators obtain for so-called "nonparametric" *kernel* estimators
$$
\hat{J_T}\equiv\hat{\gamma}_0+2\sum_{j=1}^{T-1}k\left(\frac{j}{\ell_T}\right)\hat{\gamma}_j
$$
$k$ is a kernel or weighting function, that among other things must be symmetric and have $k(0)=1$. $\ell_T$ is a bandwidth parameter that has to be chosen "appropriately".

The literature proposes a variety of choices for $k$. A popular one is the *Bartlett* kernel
$$k\left(\frac{j}{\ell_T}\right) = \begin{cases}
\bigl(1 - \frac{j}{\ell_T}\bigr)
\qquad &\mbox{for} \qquad 0 \leqslant j \leqslant \ell_T-1 \\
0 &\mbox{for} \qquad j > \ell_T-1
\end{cases}
$$
It is often the case that the choice of $k$ does not matter too much. Choosing $\ell_T$ appropriately is more important. Again, there are many rules ([Newey and West, Review of Economic Studies 1994](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs-ZSxo5DKAhUG4w4KHcJ8BGIQFgguMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ssc.wisc.edu%2F~kwest%2Fpublications%2F1990%2FAutomatic%2520Lag%2520Selection%2520in%2520Covariance%2520Matrix%2520Estimation.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEREpJozDPteukQ2zqnGRRysRPjtA)). An easy one is
$$
\ell_T=\lfloor 4(T/100)^{2/9}\rfloor
$$

Comment: Very helpful (+1). I'd commend the floor notation, at least 54 years old, for the last quantity i.e.$ \lfloor 4(T/100)^{2/9}\rfloor$.

Comment: Kenneth Eugene Iverson. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_E._Iverson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions It's a much better notation than square brackets to denote integer part, which can easily be misread as, hmm, square brackets. Also floor and its sibling ceiling simply evoke rounding down and rounding up.